# Trouble casting 1D array to 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

EDIT: C++ bits removed to avoid confusion

I have an array of data like so

```
int numSamples = 16;
float *lData  = (float*)calloc(numSamples, sizeof(float));
```

...and I would like to pass this data into a function with a definition like this . . .

```
void processSampleBlock (const float ** inputChannelData,
                         int    numInputChannels,
                         ...)
```

As you can see, this function accepts a 2D array, that can have multiple channels. My data is only a single channel (1D), but I can get the code to compile fine by doing a cast like this . .

```
processSampleBlock ((const float**)(lData),
                            1,
                            ...)
```

However, I get a bad access error at runtime then code within the function block attempts to dereference the data within the function . .

```
for (int nn=0; nn< numSamples; ++nn)
{
    float x = inputChannelData[0][nn]; //--> Computer says no
}
```

I am useless with C style multi-dimensional arrays and am probably making a fundamental error here. Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: `boost::scoped_array<float>` - Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Sorry, my problem was with the C-style bit :)

Comment: Why can't the array of pointers to the rows just contain a single pointer to a single row?

Comment: @learnvst - if you compile C-style code with a C++ compiler, it's not C code. These are two languages with subtle differences. If you intend to get a C++ answer, tag it as C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give it a pointer to an array of rows, so of you have one row give it a pointer to that row:

```
float *data = ...;
processSampleBlock(&data, 1);
```

Comment: @Bo, he said he has only 1 channel

Comment: lData.get() returns a pointer. The syntax you posted gives a compiler error

Comment: I have edited the question to remove all of the potentially confusing boosty stuff.